# foreign key brings all fields, I only want foreignkey.name Django

Tags: django, forms

```
from django.db import models
from vendors.models import Vendor

# Create your models here.

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name= ('Product Name'))
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name= ('Description'))
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= ('Cost Price'))
    selling_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= ('Selling Price'))
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}, Description: {self.description}, Vendor: {self.vendor}, Cost Price: {self.cost_price}, Selling Price: {self.selling_price},  Quantity: {self.quantity}"
```

above is my models.py
below is my forms.py

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    vendor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Vendor.objects.only('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'vendor', 'cost_price', 'selling_price', 'quantity']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['vendor'].queryset = Vendor.objects.only('name')
        self.fields['vendor'].empty_label = 'Select a vendor'

        for field_name in self.fields:
            if field_name != 'vendor':
                self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs.update({'value': ''})

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

when loading the purchaseform, I need the vendor field to populate only the name of vendor, now it's populating all fields of vendors_vendor table.

Please guide me.

Comment: class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = [('', '---------')] + list(Vendor.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name'))
        self.fields['vendor'].widget = forms.Select(choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'vendor', 'cost_price', 'selling_price', 'quantity']
----------
this way it worked, sorry for your time

Answer (score 0):

The `.label_from_instance(…)` method is related to a `ModelChoiceField`, not the form:

```
class NameModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

and then plug in that field in the form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    vendor = forms.NameModelChoiceField(queryset=Vendor.objects.only('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
            'vendor',
            'cost_price',
            'selling_price',
            'quantity',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['vendor'].empty_label = 'Select a vendor'
```